# Selecting distinct columns in DolphinDB with different methods

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I've been working on a DolphinDB query which aims to select distinct values of a column in a partitioned table. I tried three different methods and they showed different performance. I would like to understand why it is the case.

Specifically, I need to select distinct values of a non-partition column. I will give a minimal example and my three implementations.

For simplicity, I defined an in-memory partitioned table containing only two columns with 10 partitions. And I inserted into it 100,000,000 rows of random data.

```
partitionNum = 10
db = database("", VALUE, 0..(partitionNum - 1))
t = db.createPartitionedTable(table(1000:0, `id`val, [INT,INT]), `t, `id)

n = 100000000
insert into t values(rand(partitionNum, n), rand(10000000, n))
```

Then I used the following three ways to get distinct values:

1. Naively retrieve distinct values.

```
distinctVal = select distinct(val) from t
```

2. Retrieve the needed column first, and apply `distinct` to the result.

```
val = exec val from t
distinctVal = distinct(val)
```

3. Use the `group by` keyword combined with the `first` aggregate function.

```
distinctVal = select first(val) from t group by val
```

And I used `timer` to measure the elapsed time:

```
timer {
    distinctVal = select distinct(val) from t
}
// Time elapsed: 14761.95 ms

timer {
    val = exec val from t
    distinctVal = distinct(val)
}
// Time elapsed: 8269.531 ms

timer {
    distinctVal = select first(val) from t group by val
}
// Time elapsed: 3481.814 ms
```

I would like to understand why their performance are so different and whether the fastest `group by` implementation should always be used for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The function distinct is implemented with hashmap in DolphinDB and the efficiency can be affected when processing large amount of distinct records. Whereas, the SQL clauses *group by* + *frist* are based on data sorting, offering better performance for large data sets.

In the following testing case, the number of records is up to 100 million rows and k is in [0.5,1,10,50,100,500,1000,5000]*10000. Generate k distinct values with *rand(1..k, n)*. When k is smaller than 100 thousand, distinct is faster; When k is larger than 500 thousand, *group by* + *frist* outperforms *distinct*.

See code and figure on https://dolphindb1.atlassian.net/browse/SUP-1236